# Can change video quality settings for some Vimeo videos only in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, vimeo

Some of my Vimeo videos rendered in the iOS web view show the quality settings to toggle between different qualities. But in other videos, I can only see 360p quality. Is there any specific reason for this behavior?

I can toggle between qualities inside the Android Web view.

I'm using a React Native Web View to render the Vimeo player.

My web view template

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=0 minimum-scale=1">
</head>

<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="video" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script id="vimeo" async src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
  <script>
    function webViewBridge() {
      const sendEvent = (evt, data = null) => {
        // Passes events through the bridge
        var payload = {
          name: evt,
          data: data
        };
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload));
      }

      var options = { id: '${VIDEO_ID}' }
      const player = new Vimeo.Player('video', options)

      player.ready().then(function () {
        player.on('play', function () {
          sendEvent('play');
        })
        player.on('ended', function () {
          sendEvent('finish');
        })
        player.on('error', function () {
          sendEvent('error', "Player error");
        })
        sendEvent('ready');
      }).catch((e) => {
        sendEvent('error', e.message);
      })
    }

    let script = document.querySelector('#vimeo');
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
      webViewBridge();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```